# Setting class variable values dynamically with For loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i'm a beginner in python so would appreciate any help and/or suggestion.
i have a tkinter.Frame class having multiple Entry widgets. What i want is to set these entry widget's text to values from another object using a for loop with a list containing variable names or 'keys' .

i can do this by accessing every widgets separately and then using entry.insert() method.

```py
if person1.first_name is not None:
    self.first_name.insert(0, person1.first_name)
if person1.last_name is not None:
    self.last_name.insert(0, person1.last_name)
if person1.age is not None:
    self.age.insert(0, person1.age)
```

But i don't think this would be the best way if the number of widgets gets bigger.
what i want is something like this.

```py
# list containing names of entry widgets in frame class which share same name
# as object(person1) variables
list_keys = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']

def fill_entries(self, person1, list_keys)
    for x in list_keys:
        if person1.list_keys[x] is not None:
            self.list_keys[x].insert(0, str(person1.list_keys[x])
```

i want to fill the entries in frame class, if argument object values are not None.

Comment: Have you seen `getattr` and `setattr` ? So it'd be along the lines of `if getattr(person1, x) is not None: getattr(self, x).insert(0, getattr(person1, x))` kind of thing

Comment: keep it in dictionary, not as variables - `person1.data = {"first_name": Entry() }` and then you can do `person1.data["first_name"].insert()` (or `key = "first_name"` and `person1.data[key].insert()`)

Comment: @JonClements i think that is what i was looking for. I'd try these methods and see if this does the job. Thank you. :)